# How to show information in JSON format?

Tags: php, json, yii2

I have Yii2 basic, and want show page from this lesson https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2/blob/master/docs/guide/start-databases.md (without pagination)

```
Controller return:
        return $this->render('index', [
            'countries' => $countries,
            'pagination' => $pagination,
        ]);
```

View file:

```
<?php
use yii\helpers\Html;
use yii\widgets\LinkPager;
?>
    <h1>Countries</h1>
    <ul>
        <?php foreach ($countries as $country): ?>
            <li>
                <?= Html::encode("{$country->name} ({$country->code})") ?>:
                <?= $country->population ?>
            </li>
        <?php endforeach; ?>
    </ul>
```

Maybe I should change the main layout to display JSON, where and how to do it correctly?

Comment: But what's exacly the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Yii2 you need to return the result from your action, example with JSON:

```
public function actionIndex()
{
    \Yii::$app->response->format = \yii\web\Response::FORMAT_JSON;

    $query = Country::find();

    $countries = $query->orderBy('name')->all();

    return $countries;
}
```